# What does noink="true" do to paper-items?

Tags: html, attributes, polymer

In this tag:

```
<paper-item noink="true"> Some text </paper-item>
```

How does `noink="true"` affect the behavior of the `paper-item` tag?

Comment: It makes the pig silent.

Comment: @TrippKinetics: You'd think it'd be easier to have it be `oink="false"` then.

Comment: It would certainly be easier to hear across the room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `noink` attribute in Polymer disables the ripple effect that you see on click.

This isn't unique to `<paper-items>`, but rather can be applied to any Polymer elements:

```
<paper-button noink>No Ink<paper-button>
<paper-tabs noink>No Ink<paper-tabs>
```

Note that the `="true"` is not necessary; simply providing the attribute will make it true by default.